# Код из Javascript в Python

Tags: javascript, python, инспекция-кода

Есть код на JavaScript, решил переделать его под Python.

JavaScript:

```
var s = [], itoh = '0123456789ABCDEF', i;
for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    s[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10);
}

s[14] = 4;
s[19] = (s[19] & 0x3) | 0x8;

for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    s[i] = itoh[s[i]];
}

s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23] = '-';

console.log(s.join('') );
```

То что получилось у меня.

Python:

```
def generateUUID():
    import random, math
    s = []
    itoh = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    i = 0

    for i in range(36):
        random_int = (random.random() * 0x10)
        s.append(math.floor( random_int ))

    s[14] = 4
    s[19] = int( (int(s[19]) & 0x3) | 0x8 )

    for i in range(36):
        s[i] = itoh[ int(s[i]) ]
    s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23] = '-';
    result = ''.join(s)
    return result

print generateUUID()
```

Правильно ли я переделал код на Python ?

Comment: Правильно будет так https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: У автора, видимо, вторая версия, посему https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

Comment: @EgorSmolyakov правильно будет использовать третью :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая удобный синтаксис языка Python ваш код на javascript можно переписать например таким образом:

```
from random import randint

itoh = '0123456789ABCDEF'

s = [randint(0,15) for n in range(36)]
s[14], s[19] = 4, s[19] & 0x3 | 0x8 
sep = [8, 13, 18, 23]

UUID = ''.join([itoh[s[n]] if n not in sep else '-' for n in range(36)])
```

Получаем рандомный UUID:

```
'25962063-437F-49B4-84F6-370FCBB1CB23'
```

Можно вообще все в 2 строчки уместить но удобочитаемости не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем изобретать велосипед:

```
#python 3
from uuid import uuid1
print(uuid1())
# 4ed4e86c-c2d6-11e7-999e-f832e48c87b5
```